# crash while scrolling through the TableView which haves a Collectionview in it

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, uicollectionview

i was having this issue ([UICollectionView inside of UITableViewCell - AutoLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574881/uicollectionview-inside-of-uitableviewcell-autolayout))

and after trying several solution which are available in the internet i came with this [@Pablo Romeu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126708/uicollectionview-inside-a-uitableviewcell-dynamic-height) i tried his solution , now i got a TableView with collectionView cells in it (which can dynamically change its size according to content in it)
 but when am scrolling through my tableview its getting crashed with this error :

```
    2016-06-13 22:05:51.546 WishMeluck[3507:425240] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2016-06-13 22:05:51.546 WishMeluck[3507:425240] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2016-06-13 22:05:51.546 WishMeluck[3507:425240] Please check the values return by the delegate.
2016-06-13 22:05:51.547 WishMeluck[3507:425240] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fb83c05de90>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fb83a0c7c00; frame = (0 82.5; 375 179); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 4; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fb83c05cf00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb83c055fb0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {539, 179}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fb83c05de90>.
2016-06-13 22:05:51.547 WishMeluck[3507:425240] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2016-06-13 22:05:51.548 WishMeluck[3507:425240] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2016-06-13 22:05:51.548 WishMeluck[3507:425240] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2016-06-13 22:05:51.548 WishMeluck[3507:425240] Please check the values return by the delegate.
2016-06-13 22:05:51.548 WishMeluck[3507:425240] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fb83c05de90>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fb83a0c7c00; frame = (0 82.5; 375 179); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 4; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fb83c05cf00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb83c055fb0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {539, 179}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fb83c05de90>.
2016-06-13 22:05:51.548 WishMeluck[3507:425240] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
(lldb)
```

am not able to figure out the cause of this error if any body knows then please help me out

added this codes to my TableViewCell

```
        override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

//        collectionViewContainer.frame = self.bounds;
//        collectionViewContainer.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

        let flow: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout)
        // Configure the collectionView
        flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
            // This enables the magic of auto layout.
            // Setting estimatedItemSize different to CGSizeZero
            // on flow Layout enables auto layout for collectionView cells.
            // https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-226/
            flow.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1)
        // Disable the scroll on your collection view
        // to avoid running into multiple scroll issues.
        self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = true
    }

    func bindWithModel(model: AnyObject) {
        // Do your stuff here to configure the tableViewCell
        // Tell the cell to redraw its contentView



        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    // THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT METHOD
    //
    // This method tells the auto layout
    // You cannot calculate the collectionView content size in any other place,
    // because you run into race condition issues.
    // NOTE: Works for iOS 8 or later

    override func systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
        // With autolayout enabled on collection view's cells we need to force a collection view relayout with the shown size (width)


        //self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, targetSize.width, targetSize.height)
        self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        // If the cell's size has to be exactly the content
        // Size of the collection View, just return the
        // collectionViewLayout's collectionViewContentSize.
        return self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize()
    }
```

and this in my CollectionViewCell:

```
    class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {

        self.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
    }


}
```

also this in my TableViewController:

```
    // Enable automatic row auto layout calculations
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
// Set the estimatedRowHeight to a non-0 value to enable auto layout.
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

my project [file](http://www.filetolink.com/bc0fe2eec4)

Answer (score 1):

your problem stay at this line

```
return self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize()
```

I had replaced with

```
return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize().width, 300);
```

and don't crash but I am sure that this is not that you want so maybe you can see the problem better with this hint

Comment: @Rienier thanks for responding man , i tired this but its crashing the app with n invite loop of NSLog errors

Comment: I am reviewing to see if I can fix this issue, any result I will share in my answer by edit